# How be sure on_epoch_end triggers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, dataset

I made a simple HDF5 reader class to avoid loading entire dataset in memory. I used sequence class to do so, but I'm not sure if on_epoch_end() function will trigger correctly.

I put a single print inside it, but it never appear! So I think there is something wrong in my code:

```
class HDF5Generator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, hdf5_file, shuffle=True):
        print("GENERATED")
        self.hdf5 = h5py.File(hdf5_file, 'r')
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.indices = list(range(0, len(self.hdf5["samples"])))
        random.Random().shuffle(self.indices)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.hdf5["samples"])

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.hdf5["samples"][self.indices[idx]], self.hdf5["labels"][self.indices[idx]]

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        print("RE-SHUFFLE")
        random.Random().shuffle(self.indices)
```

Here how I use it:

```
d = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(HD5FGenerator, args=[dataset], output_signature=(...))
d = d.batch(batch_size).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE).cache()
...
model.fit(d, epochs=epochs)
```

In console appear the epoch counter, the progress bar, the string "GENERATED" but never "RE-SHUFFLE"

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since seems to be a TF bug, I found a workaround to trigger `on_epoch_end()` of my generator.

```py
class CallbackOnEpochEnd(Callback):
    def __init__(self, generator):
        super(CallbackOnEpochEnd, self).__init__()
        self.generator = generator

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.generator.on_epoch_end()

[...]

generator = HDF5Generator()
d = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: generator, output_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(5,20)), tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1,))))

[...]

on_epoch_end_callback = CallbackOnEpochEnd(generator)

[...]

model.fit(d, epochs=5, callbacks=[on_epoch_end_callback])
```

With this "RE-SHUFFLE" appear on console after every epoch!